# Pesquisar intervalo de números no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, query

Boa tarde.

No ERP do cliente, no cadastro de calçados a informação de grade é trazida no formato de string, por exemplo "27 ao 40". Essa informação vai para o mysql do site através de uma carga automática do servidor.

Bom, lá no site eles gostariam de implementar a busca por numeração, filtrando por exemplo pelo número "32", então de que forma eu poderia realizar essa pesquisa sendo que a grade me trás somente "27 ao 40"?

Comment: Você tem no banco 27 ao 40?

Comment: Poste como é a estrutura da sua table pf

Comment: A estrutura é bem simples: id | referencia | categoria | grade